# How to parse complex json with python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse this json file and I am having trouble.
The json looks like this:

```
    <ListObject list at 0x2161945a860> JSON: {
  "data": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "available_on": 1621382400,
      "created": 1621264875,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "0123456",
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 266,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 266,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "processing fees",
          "type": "fee"
        }
      ],
      "id": "txn_abvgd1234",
      "net": 9999,
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "reporting_category": "charge",
      "source": "cust1",
      "sourced_transfers": {
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/source"
      },
      "status": "pending",
      "type": "charge"
    },
    {
      "amount": 25984,
      "available_on": 1621382400,
      "created": 1621264866,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "0326489",
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 93,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 93,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "processing fees",
          "type": "fee"
        }
      ],
      "id": "txn_65987jihgf4984oihydgrd",
      "net": 9874,
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "reporting_category": "charge",
      "source": "cust2",
      "sourced_transfers": {
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/source"
      },
      "status": "pending",
      "type": "charge"
    },
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "object": "list",
  "url": "/v1/balance_"
}
```

I am trying to parse it in python with this script:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(json)
df.head()
```

but what I am getting is:

[image]

What i need is to parse each of these data points in its own column. So i will have 2 row of data with columns for each data points.
Something like this:

[image]

How do i do this now?

Comment: All it takes is a little preprocessing, converting your dictionary to a list of tuples.  Do that BEFORE you suck it into pandas, and it should just flow in.

Comment: If you tell us what the resulting columns should be, perhaps someone will write the code, but it's a simple this-to-that conversion.

Comment: @TimRoberts - i just edited my original question and added example of what i am trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All but one of your fields are direct copies from the JSON, so you can just make a list of the fields you can copy, and then do the extra processing for the fee_details.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

inp =  """{
  "data": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "available_on": 1621382400,
      "created": 1621264875,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "0123456",
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 266,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 266,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "processing fees",
          "type": "fee"
        }
      ],
      "id": "txn_abvgd1234",
      "net": 9999,
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "reporting_category": "charge",
      "source": "cust1",
      "sourced_transfers": {
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/source"
      },
      "status": "pending",
      "type": "charge"
    },
    {
      "amount": 25984,
      "available_on": 1621382400,
      "created": 1621264866,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "0326489",
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 93,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 93,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "processing fees",
          "type": "fee"
        }
      ],
      "id": "txn_65987jihgf4984oihydgrd",
      "net": 9874,
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "reporting_category": "charge",
      "source": "cust2",
      "sourced_transfers": {
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/source"
      },
      "status": "pending",
      "type": "charge"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "object": "list",
  "url": "/v1/balance_"
}"""

copies = [
    'id',
    'net',
    'object',
    'reporting_category',
    'source',
    'amount',
    'available_on',
    'created',
    'currency',
    'description',
    'exchange_rate',
    'fee'
]

data = json.loads(inp)
rows = []
for inrow in data['data']:
    outrow = {}
    for copy in copies:
        outrow[copy] = inrow[copy]
    outrow['fee_details'] = inrow['fee_details'][0]['description']
    rows.append(outrow)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
                           id   net               object reporting_category source  amount  ...     created  currency description exchange_rate  fee      fee_details
0               txn_abvgd1234  9999  balance_transaction             charge  cust1     100  ...  1621264875       usd     0123456          None  266  processing fees
1  txn_65987jihgf4984oihydgrd  9874  balance_transaction             charge  cust2   25984  ...  1621264866       usd     0326489          None   93  processing fees

[2 rows x 13 columns]
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Comment: Awesome. This was quick